# Packrat with local binary repository

Tags: r, packrat

I want to use `packrat` on a Windows 7 machine with no internet connection.
I have downloaded all binary packages from `http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/` into the local folder `C:/xyz/CRAN_3_1`.

The problem is now that

```
packrat::init(options=list(local.repos="C:/xyz/CRAN_3_1"))
```

throws a bunch of warnings and errors like

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio/bin/...
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio/src/...
Fetching sources for Rcpp (0.11.4) ... Failed
Package Rcpp not available in repository or locally
```

As it seems `packrat` tries to find

1. the binary version of `Rcpp` on CRAN (fails since there is no internet connection)
2. the source of `Rcpp` on CRAN (fails since there is no internet connection)
3. the local source of the package (fails since I only have the binaries)

What I don't understand is why `packrat` does not also search for the *local* *binary* package...

**Question 1:** I could download the source CRAN repository to get around this problem. But I would like to know from you guys whether there is an easier solution to this, *i.e.*, whether it is possible to make `packrat` accept a local binary repo.

**Question 2**: When I create my own package `myPackage` with packrat enabled, will the `myPackage`-specific local `packrat` library also be included in the package? That is, assume that I give the binary `myPackage` zip File to one of my colleagues who does not have one of the packages that `myPackage` depends on (let's say `Rcpp`). Will `Rcpp` be included in `myPackage` when I use `packrat`? Or does my colleague have to install `Rcpp` himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to hack around this problem. Please bear in mind that I have never used `packrat` before and that I do not know its "proper" behaviour. But my impression is that the hack works.
Here is how I did it:

1. Open your project, load `packrat` via `library(packrat)`
2. type `fixInNamespace("snapshotImpl",ns="packrat")` - a window opens - copy its content into the clipboard
3. Go to `/yourProjDir/` and create a file `snapshotImplFix.R`
4. Copy the clipboard's content into this file ...
5. ... but change the first line to

   `snapshotImplFix=function (project, available = NULL, lib.loc = libDir(project), 
   dry.run = FALSE, ignore.stale = FALSE, prompt = interactive(), 
   auto.snapshot = FALSE, verbose = TRUE, fallback.ok = FALSE, 
   snapshot.sources = FALSE)`

   Note `snapshot.sources = FALSE`! Save and close the file.
6. Create `/yourProjDir/.Rprofile` and add

   `setHook(packageEvent("packrat","onLoad"),function(...) {`
   `source("./snapshotImplFix.R");`
   `tmpfun=get("snapshotImpl",envir=asNamespace("packrat"));`
   `environment(snapshotImplFix)=environment(tmpfun);`
   `utils::assignInNamespace(x="snapshotImpl",value=snapshotImplFix,ns="packrat");})`

   Points 2-6 fix the problem with the `snapshot.sources` argument being `TRUE` by default (I did not find a better way to change that...)
7. Finally, we have to tell `packrat` to take our local repository. It's important that you have the right folder structure. Therefore I moved the repo from `C:/xyz/CRAN_3_1` to `C:/xyz/CRAN_3_1/bin/windows/contrib/3.1`. Do not forget to run `library(tools);write_PACKAGES("C:/xyz/CRAN_3_1/bin/windows/contrib/3.1");` if you also have to move your files.
8. Open `yourProjDir/.Rprofile` again and add at the end

   `local({r=getOption("repos");r["CRAN"]="file:///C:/xyz/CRAN_3_1";r["CRANextra"]=r["CRAN"];options(repos=r)})`

   Note the 3 `/` right after `file`! Save and exit file.
9. Close the project and re-open.
10. Now you can execute `packrat::init()` and it should run without errors.

It would be great if someone with more experience regarding `packrat` could give his/her input so that I can be sure that this hack works. Any pointers to proper solutions are highly appreciated, of course.